# Calling a python script developed under anaconda from python script through Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, virtualenv

I was making a QT GUI wherein I have to call another python script which was developed under anaconda environment, now problem is I have to call that script from my GUI Application which is being developed using pycharm.

I was using subprocess.getstatusoutput('conda test.py')

Comment: Could you please clarify what the question is?

Comment: I have two environment, one for pycharm using virtual env based on (c:\user\uname\AppData\Programs\Python) where I have QT installed and another my anaconda environment based on conda environment I have opencv installed. Now what i want to do is run a script on pycharm which opens up my GUI and within that i have a button which on clicking should run another script uisng my anaconda python executable